# Why is this compound more basic than the other?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

So, the original question was which compound is more basic.

[image: Compound A]
[image: Compound B]

Compound A and Compound B respectively.

My reasoning is that on protonation, Compound B would be more stable than Compound A as well, Compound B is an allylic nitrogen cation. Thus, compound B should be more basic.

[image][image]

Why don't nitrogen cations act similar to carbo cations in this case?

But the given answer is that compound A is more basic, because of being connected to a sp2 hybridized carbon. Another given reason was that the first cation was stabilized by water while the second one wasn't?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Being connected to a sp2 hybridised carbon makes it weaker not stronger. Still, enamines can be even weaker because of mesomeric effects.

Comment: @Mithoron, I know right! I was like, that sp2 reasoning doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The lone pair in B is conjugated with the C=C bond. Similar to the nitrogen lone pair in an amide, which is also not very basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What may be happening is that the A cation has a resonance structure where the $\pi$ bond polarizes to the nitrogen and thus turns the $sp^2$ carbon into a carbocation center (leaving the nitrogen formally uncharged). This carbocation contribution is enhanced by the $sp^2$ carbon also hyperconjugating with the carbon atom next to it in the ring. Also the B cation cannot form an allylic structure because protonation of the nitrogen atom in that compound saturates it.

Answer (score 1):

The A ammonium ion is sp2 hybridized so less basic[really the ion is more acidic] than an sp3 nitrogen. However, the enamine structure in B delocalizes the electron pair over the nitrogen and the double bound reducing basicity even more. There is no resonance of an ammonium ion with a double bond; there are no orbitals available on the nitrogen to accept electrons to reduce the charge[except antibonding].